# Chrome Dev Editor: How to change the default tab size to 4 spaces?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, text-editors

I'm using Google's [Chrome Dev Editor - developer preview](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor). It is a Chrome extension available in the Chrome store. When I use the tab key on my keyboard, 2 spaces are indented. My aim is to change this to 4 spaces.

I've tried going to the Settings menu but there are very few options available and setting the default tab size isn't one of them.

Any idea how I can change the default tab size to 4 spaces?

Comment: I have found documentation on the file [ide/web/prefs.json](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/924bd8844a05aedaa02dfdd3fa5fe38ad1e6e394/ide/web/prefs.json) where the "indentation" section looks pretty promising. It contains values for "useTabs" and for "width", whose default is 2. See if you can find such a file in your distribution and change width to 4. See also [ide/web/test/editor_config_test.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/76c8a9013031a551a3fbdd71974e3b44fb86ccca/ide/web/test/editor_config_test.dart).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to find that file. It does look promising!

Comment: Any news about these 2 files ?

Answer (score 1):

How about an Autohotkey solution (*"When native tools fail: AUTOHOTKEY!*")? Small, portable, customizable.

```
#IfWinActive Chrome Dev Editor (developer preview)
TAB::
Send {space 4}
sleep 20
```

The first line indicates that TAB works normally unless the Dev Editor window is active. Note that this matches the name exactly, so if the window-title changed in future, the script would break.

The last line is a delay in ms between repeated SEND events to prevent spamming. You can alter it depending on typing speed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll definitely keep it in mind but I'd prefer to learn how to change the app's config in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Examining the sources of the Chrome Dev Editor, I have found documentation on two files
that look pretty promising :

[**ide/web/prefs.json**](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/924bd8844a05aedaa02dfdd3fa5fe38ad1e6e394/ide/web/prefs.json)

```
{
  "stripWhitespaceOnSave": true,
  "editorFontSize": 12,
  "editorTheme": null,
  "keyBindings": null,
  "indentation":{
    "default":{
      "useTabs": false,
      "width": 2
    },
    "dart":{
      "useTabs": false,
      "width": 2
    }
  }
}
```

The "indentation" section contains `width`, whose default is 2. See if you can find such a file in your distribution and change the width to 4.

[**ide/web/test/editor_config_test.dar**](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/76c8a9013031a551a3fbdd71974e3b44fb86ccca/ide/web/test/editor_config_test.dart)

This contains a section on the edit configuration per file-type.
It might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty). Do you know where I can find the prefs.json file in my file system?

Comment: Should be easy enough to [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) : `find / prefs.json` or similar.

Comment: I found the file! Unfortunately, the change you suggested didn't work in my case. Tabs remain 2 spaces even when I update the file with sudo privileges.

Comment: For the other file, is editor_config_test.dar relevant for you ? It might be that this file negates the change in the other one. Of course, as part of the sources, a recompile of the Chrome Dev Editor might be required to have effect (but if so this would be very poor software design).

Answer (score 0):

According to this link:

https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/issues/3861

the file to change is `ide/web/lib/ace.dart`.

change the line `session.tabSize = 2;`

PS: The folder is located in `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I opened that issue, and if you take a look at the last few replies in the thread, you'll see the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry. I should have looked